# How to check struct data value in a switch statement expression

Tags: c, struct, switch-statement

My code:

```
#define qty     2
typedef struct { uint8_t ID;
                 uint8_t tagbyte[5];  
               } cards;

const cards eecollcards[qty] EEMEM ={
                                      {0x01, {0x2A, 0x00, 0x24, 0x91, 0xFD}},
                                      {0x02, {0x4F, 0x00, 0x88, 0x59, 0xB0}},
                                    };
int main (void)
while (1)
{
  switch (<what goes here?>)
  {
    case 0x01: .....
      break;
    case 0x02: .....
      break;
  }
}
```

I want to check values held in a `struct` by differentiating between the values 0x01 and 0x02, but I have problems forming the `switch` statement shown above. I have tried `cards.uint8_t ID` and `eecollcards[qty] EEMEM` but these generate errors such as the following:

`error: excepted expression before struct...`

I know that `cards` is just a name of a type and not a variable.  0x01 refers to the `ID` variable of type `uint8_t` and the remaining hex values are for initialization of the `tagbyte[5]` array.

Comment: Do you want to cycle over all elements in `eeecollcards`?

Comment: const cards eecollcards[qty] EEMEM = .... won't compile

Comment: @Manül it would, it seems to be some kind of embedded system EEPROM identifier.

Comment: Yes the values are stored in EEPROM using EEMEM. Ty for your answers, it is working fine now with Manül's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int main()
{
  int i;
  const cards eecollcards[qty] ={
                                {0x01, {0x2A, 0x00, 0x24, 0x91, 0xFD}},
                                {0x02, {0x4F, 0x00, 0x88, 0x59, 0xB0}},
                                };
  for (i = 0; i < qty; i++)
  {
    switch(eecollcards[i].ID)
    {
      case 0x01: //.....
        break;
      case 0x02: //.....
        break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I removed the EEMEM, otherwise it wouldn't compile on my system

Answer (score 1):

`EEMEM` just tells the compiler where to store your data (apparently in EEPROM...). To read from it, you just use the variables name and an index (this will loop over all elements):

```
int i = 0;
while (i < qty) {
  switch (eecollcards[i].ID) {
  ...
  }
  i++;
}
```